# How can I retrieve a distinct count of rows from a specific column Mongo DB collection via a Laravel REST Api controller?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a React-based web application that's being supported on the back-end by a REST API written in Laravel. I need to display the count of from a specific column in a collection in the database, after which it will be displayed on the dashboard. This should be retrieved from the back-end via a Mongo DB query and an API call to the back-end. Being new to Laravel/MongoDb, I run into a blocker when trying to get this implementation done on my controller - this is the part I need ideas on the implementation - basically how to make the request to the db and retrieving the result. The code below shows what I have so far:

My mongodb query which works on the mongo shell and returns **167** as the count:

`db.users.distinct('policy_scheme').length`

php code:

api.php:

`Route::get('totalSchemes', [CollectionController::class, 'numberOfSchemes']);`

Controller:

`

```
        public function numberOfSchemes(Request $request)
    {

        $schemeCount = DB::collection('users')::distinct()->get(['policy_scheme'])->count();


        if(!empty($schemeCount)){
            return response()->json([
            'message'=>'data', 
            'data'=> $schemeCount], 201);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
            'message'=>'No data', 
            'data'=>[] ], 201);
        }


    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this one.

```php
$schemeCount = DB::collection('users')::unique('id')->get(['policy_scheme'])->count();
```

Comment: Okay thank you. How about full controller implementation?